# TableSorter.java is missing in the Package org/eclipse/ui/views/markers/internal for Eclipse 3.7.2

Tags: java, eclipse, tablesorter, eclipse-indigo

I am trying to update eclipse from my project from 3.2.2 to 3.7.2. and found that TableSorter.java is missing in the package org/eclipse/ui/views/markers/internal. I tried to search it on google but found nothing related to this topic. Can someone please tell me what could be the alternative for TableSorter.java for 3.7.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `org/eclipse/ui/views/markers/internal` is an internal package and is not part of the Eclipse API (see [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-API-Use/index.html)). As such it is subject to change without notice and this is what has happened.

On a quick check `TableSorter` was removed in release 3.4 and replaced with `TableComparator` again this is an internal class.